# Fibonacci with Python: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, fibonacci

I was trying to write a program to compute the Fibonacci number using Python:

```
n = int(input())

def fib(n):
    a = []
    if (n <=1):
        return n
    else:
        for i in range(2, n):
            a.append(a[-1] + a[-2])
        return a[i]
print (fib(n))
```

However, I can't print out the expected result. For example, after I typed in the number 8, the following message popped up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fibonacci.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (fib(n))
  File "fibonacci.py", line 9, in fib
    a.append(a[-1] + a[-2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What went wrong in the process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` your'e starting out with an empty array and trying to access index's on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to populate your list with first 2 numbers of Fibonacci sequence:

```
a = [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

-2 and -1 indexes are not available if you don't set them in "a" list before using.

```
n = int(input())

def fib(n):
    a = [0, 1]
    if n <=1:
        return n
    else:
        for i in range(2, n):
            a.append(a[-1] + a[-2])
        return a[i]
print (fib(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in your code

```
n = int(input())

def fib(n):
    a = [0,1]  # add these values to your array to intialize
    if (n <=1):
        return n
    else:
        for i in range(2, n):
            a.append(a[-1] + a[-2])
    return a  # change this also so that you can get all the values returned at the same time

print (fib(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function to compute any Fibonacci series number

```
def Fibonacci(n): 
    if n<0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
# First Fibonacci number is 0 
    elif n==0: 
        return 0
# Second Fibonacci number is 1 
    elif n==1: 
        return 1
    else: 
        return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
```

Or you can use this formula the formula for nth term in the fibonacci series.

```
Fn = {[(√5 + 1)/2] ^ n} / √5
```